VBA function to identify correct assembly in Truth Table
I am trying to write a VBA function that solves for the correct assembly by identifying if the model digits in a row are true when compared to a model number. There are multiple sheets. Each sheet is an "assembly family".
The model number is 18 digits long, and each sheet solves based on different model digits.. If part of a column is blank, that means it is only evaluated if there is data in the cell, otherwise it is "Tru".
Here are a few valid model numbers:
CMP24FDMCABHNN05NN
SMG24BDFLCSXNA8216
CMD24BDMEASHSN82N2
The raw data from two sheets is below.





Column   Desc
Product Type
Unit Config
Nominal Capacity
Generation
Ventilation Configuration
Case Construction
# TRU




Digit #
1,2
3
4,5
7
9
11
1


Part #
C_005_PT
C_005_UC
C_005_MBH
C_005_G
C_005_VC
C_005_CC
Evaluate


3H2000640116
CM
D,P
24,36
D
A,B,C,E,Q
B
F


3H2000640120
CM
D,P
24,36
D
A,B,C,E,Q
A
F


3H2000640120
CM
D,P
24,36
D
A,B,C,E,Q
S
TRU


3H2000640216
CM,SM
G,W,S
24,36
D
F,G,H,K,L,M,P,R,S
B
F


3H2000640220
CM,SM
G,W,S
24,36
D
F,G,H,K,L,M,P,R,S
A
F


3H2000640220
CM,SM
G,W,S
24,36
D
F,G,H,K,L,M,P,R,S
S
F


3H2000640316
CM,SM
G,W,S
24,36
D
A,B,Q
B
F


3H2000640320
CM,SM
G,W,S
24,36
D
A,B,Q
A
F


3H2000640320
CM,SM
G,W,S
24,36
D
A,B,Q
S
F


3H2000650116
CM
D,P
48
D
A,B,C,E,Q
B
F


3H2000650120
CM
D,P
48
D
A,B,C,E,Q
A
F


3H2000650216
CM,SM
G,W,S
48,60
D
F,G,H,K,L,M,P,R,S
B
F


3H2000650220
CM,SM
G,W,S
48,60
D
F,G,H,K,L,M,P,R,S
A
F


3H2000650316
CM,SM
G,W,S
48,60
D
A,B,Q
B
F


3H2000650320
CM,SM
G,W,S
48,60
D
A,B,Q
A
F


3H2000660120
CM
D,P
48
D
A,B,C,E,Q
S
F


3H2000660220
CM,SM
G,W,S
48,60
D
F,G,H,K,L,M,P,R,S
S
F


3H2000660320
CM,SM
G,W,S
48,60
D
A,B,Q
S
F


3H2000670116
CM
D,P
60
D
A,B,C,E,Q
B
F


3H2000670120
CM
D,P
60
D
A,B,C,E,Q
A
F


3H2000680120
CM
D,P
60
D
A,B,C,E,Q
S
F






Column   Desc
Product Type
Unit Config
Nominal Capacity
Generation
HGRH
Coaxial Coil Option
# TRU




Digit #
1,2
3
4,5
7
14
17
1


Part #
C_005_PT
C_005_UC
C_005_MBH
C_005_G
C_005_HG
C_005_CO
Evaluate


3H2000762400
CM
D
24
D
N,C

TRU


3H2000763600
CM
D
36
D
N,C

F


3H2000764800
CM
D
48
D
N,C

F


3H2000762410
CM
D
24
D
A,B

F


3H2000763610
CM
D
36
D
A,B

F


3H2000764810
CM
D
48
D
A,B

F


3H2000772400
CM
P
24
D
N,C

F


3H2000773600
CM
P
36
D
N,C

F


3H2000774800
CM
P
48
D
N,C

F


3H2000772410
CM
P
24
D
A,B

F


3H2000773610
CM
P
36
D
A,B

F


3H2000774810
CM
P
48
D
A,B

F


3H2000752401
CM
S
24
D
N,C
T
F


3H2000753601
CM
S
36
D
N,C
T
F


3H2000754801
CM
S
48
D
N,C
T
F


3H2000756001
CM
S
60
D
N,C
T
F


3H2000766000
CM
D
60
D
N,C

F


3H2000766010
CM
D
60
D
A,B

F


3H2000776000
CM
P
60
D
N,C

F



Currently, I solve for this manually with this tricky equation that is horrible to maintain.
=IF(AND(MID(Test!$S$2,1,2)=B61,
        OR(MID(Test!$S$2,3,1)=MID(C61,1,1),
           MID(Test!$S$2,3,1)=MID(C61,3,1),C61=""),
           MID(Test!$S$2,4,2)=D61,
           OR(MID(Test!$S$2,7,1)=MID(E61,1,1),
              MID(Test!$S$2,7,1)=MID(E61,3,1),E61=""),
        OR(MID(Test!$S$2,14,1)=MID(F61,1,1),
           MID(Test!$S$2,14,1)=MID(F61,3,1),
           MID(Test!$S$2,14,1)=MID(F61,5,1),
           MID(Test!$S$2,14,1)=MID(F61,7,1)),
        OR(MID(Test!$S$2,17,1)=G61,G61="")),"TRU","F")

The above function is an IF AND OR evaluator. It reads each cell and compares it to a model number on another sheet. The extra OR statements are used to parse cells that have multiple values that could be true. "CM,SM".
The expected output is simply if the assembly number is true when compared to the model number. There should only one true per sheet.
ideally, I turn this into a recursive function, but I am having trouble writing it without hardcoding the digits into the script

Maybe you could explain the rules around the matching?  Just as your function is "horrible" to maintain, it's not much fun for us to parse out its content....


The 1st argument: model number (18 chars)
The 2nd argument: the range of model data (6 cells)
UDF returns "!Err" if the argument is invalid.

Option Explicit

Function ValModel(ByVal sMod As String, Rng As Range) As String
    Dim arr, aTxt(1 To 6) As String, i As Long
    Const COMMA = ","
    Application.Volatile
    If Rng.Count <> 6 Or Rng.Rows.Count > 1 Or Len(sMod) <> 18 Then
        ValModel = "!Err"
    Else
        ValModel = "F"
        arr = Rng.Value
        aTxt(1) = COMMA & Left(sMod, 2) & COMMA
        aTxt(2) = COMMA & Mid(sMod, 3, 1) & COMMA
        aTxt(3) = COMMA & Mid(sMod, 4, 2) & COMMA
        aTxt(4) = COMMA & Mid(sMod, 7, 1) & COMMA
        aTxt(5) = COMMA & Mid(sMod, 9, 1) & COMMA
        aTxt(6) = COMMA & Mid(sMod, 11, 1) & COMMA
        For i = 1 To 6
            arr(1, i) = COMMA & arr(1, i) & COMMA
            If InStr(1, arr(1, i), aTxt(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        ValModel = "Tru"
    End If
End Function




The Digit # row is different on sheets. The 3rd argument is introduced.

Note: It supports the dynamic configuration of Digit #. But its performance is worse than the first UDF.
Function ValModel2(ByVal sMod As String, ProdRng As Range, ParaRng As Range) As String
    Dim arrProd, arrPara, aTxt() As String, i As Long, iLen As Long, aPara
    Const COMMA = ","
    Application.Volatile
    If ParaRng.Rows.Count > 1 Or ProdRng.Rows.Count > 1 Or _
            Len(sMod) <> 18 Or ParaRng.Count <> ProdRng.Count Then
        ValModel2 = "!Err"
    Else
        ValModel2 = "F"
        arrProd = ProdRng.Value
        arrPara = ParaRng.Value
        ReDim aTxt(1 To ParaRng.Count)
        For i = 1 To UBound(aTxt)
            aPara = Split(arrPara(1, i), ",")
            If UBound(aPara) = 0 Then
                iLen = 1
            Else
                iLen = CInt(aPara(UBound(aPara))) - CInt(aPara(0)) + 1
            End If
            aTxt(i) = COMMA & Mid(sMod, CInt(aPara(0)), iLen) & COMMA
        Next
        For i = 1 To 6
            If Len(arrProd(1, i)) > 0 Then
                arrProd(1, i) = COMMA & arrProd(1, i) & COMMA
                If InStr(1, arrProd(1, i), aTxt(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ValModel2 = "Tru"
    End If
End Function



This works for the first dataset, but you'll see the second dataset is evaluated via different model digits. First if 1/2,3,4/5,7,9,11 second dataset is 1/2,3,4/5,7,14,17
Also, it is not always evaluated with 6 truth columns, sometimes it is one and other times it is 9.

I was working on a flexible UDF. Pls try the updated code.
